# perl specify unicode character by name without putting name in all caps

Tags: perl, unicode

So, this is sort of a cosmetic point, but is there an easy way to insert a unicode character by its name inside a Perl string and give the name "normal" casing?

Perl includes unicode literals that look up code points by name, as in the following:

```
"\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA}"
```

I find something like the following easier to read:

```
  "\N{Greek Small Letter Alpha}",
```

As far as I know there are no case minimal pairs when it comes to unicode character names. Is there a concise way to name the character that still triggers a `compilation error` very early in the  process of executing a script if the character doesn't exist?

example compilation error with intentionally misspelled character name, this is the kind of check I don't want to give up.

```
$ echo '%[a]' | ./unicodify 
Unknown charname 'GREK SMALL LETTER ALPHA' at ./unicodify line 10, within string

Execution of ./unicodify aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I'm trying to write a small utility to make it easier to enter unicode characters in text files by mnemonic names delimited by `%[` and `]`.

Here's an extremely stripped down example that just replaces `%[a]` and `%[b]`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;
use open ':std' => ':utf8';

my %abbrevs = (
  'a' => "\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA}",
  'b' => "\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA}",
);

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my $line = $_;
  $line =~ s/(\%\[(.*?)\])/$abbrevs{$2}/g;
  print "${line}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote [charnames](https://metacpan.org/pod/charnames),

> Starting in Perl v5.16, any occurrence of `\N{`*`CHARNAME`*`}` sequences in a double-quotish string automatically loads this module with arguments `:full` and `:short` (described below) if it hasn't already been loaded with different arguments

On of those "different arguments" requests the use of loose matching.

```
$ perl -CSD -e'
   use charnames ":loose";
   CORE::say "\N{Greek Small Letter Alpha}";
'
α
```

> LOOSE MATCHES
>
> By specifying `:loose`, Unicode's [loose character name matching](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44#Matching_Rules) rules are selected instead of the strict exact match used otherwise. That means that *CHARNAME* doesn't have to be so precisely specified. Upper/lower case doesn't matter (except with scripts as mentioned above), nor do any underscores, and the only hyphens that matter are those at the beginning or end of a word in the name (with one exception: the hyphen in U+1180 `HANGUL JUNGSEONG O-E` does matter). Also, blanks not adjacent to hyphens don't matter. The official Unicode names are quite variable as to where they use hyphens versus spaces to separate word-like units, and this option allows you to not have to care as much. The reason non-medial hyphens matter is because of cases like U+0F60 `TIBETAN LETTER -A` versus U+0F68 `TIBETAN LETTER A`. The hyphen here is significant, as is the space before it, and so both must be included.
>
> `:loose` slows down look-ups by a factor of 2 to 3 versus `:full`, but the trade-off may be worth it to you. Each individual look-up takes very little time, and the results are cached, so the speed difference would become a factor only in programs that do look-ups of many different spellings, and probably only when those look-ups are through `vianame()` and `string_vianame()`, since `\N{...}` look-ups are done at compile time.

The module also provides the means for creating custom aliases.